# What is the definition of a strong type?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, stability-theory

I know the definition of a type over a set of parameters but can not find any definition for strong type. For example what does it mean to write $stp(a/A)$ ?

Comment: http://modeltheory.wikia.com/wiki/Strong_type

Comment: Thanks a lot :)